# Can a constexpr in a derived class initialize a base class member without instantiating any of the classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, c++17, constexpr

I have some generic functionality that I want to implement only once in a base class. I have many (many!) different cases having the same structure but different data on which this functionality should be applied. Each derived class implements its own dataset. These derived classes will be auto generated by some external code.

See below for a compilable and runnable example. Currently I can call the `getData()` method below after instantiating the corresponding derived class.

```
#include<array>
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct
{
    int id;
    int size;
};

class myBase
{
protected:
    const myStruct *myStructArray;

    myBase(const myStruct *structArray)
    {
        myStructArray = structArray;
    };

public:
    // This functionality is in my real case much more complex.
    // I want to define this functionality only once, and not repeatetly in the derived classes as it will become unmainainable.
    // But since all information is known at compile time and const, I want to be able to access this method staticially as:
    // `myDerived1::getData(1);`, thus without having to instantiate the 'myDerived1' class.
    myStruct getData(int index)
    {
        return *(myStructArray + index);
    }
};

// An example of a derived class defining the data.
class myDerived1 : public myBase
{
    constexpr static auto carrFieldMetaData{
        []() { // A lambda function that initializes the array as a constexpr where the array indexes are explicitly denoted.
            std::array<myStruct, 2> myStructData{};
            myStructData[0] = {.id = 0, .size = 1};
            myStructData[1] = {.id = 1, .size = 2};
            return myStructData;
        }()};

public:
    myDerived1() : myBase(carrFieldMetaData.data()){};
};

// Another example of the derived class with the same structure but different data.
class myDerived2 : public myBase
{
    constexpr static auto carrFieldMetaData{
        []() { // A lambda function that initializes the array as a constexpr where the array indexes are explicitly denoted.
            std::array<myStruct, 3> myStructData{};
            myStructData[0] = {.id = 0, .size = 8};
            myStructData[1] = {.id = 1, .size = 9};
            myStructData[2] = {.id = 2, .size = 1};
            return myStructData;
        }()};

public:
    myDerived2() : myBase(carrFieldMetaData.data()){};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    myBase test = myDerived1();
    std::cout << test.getData(0).size << '\n';
    std::cout << test.getData(1).size << '\n';
};
```

I tried to make the data definition `constexpr` since all information is already known at compile time. So I figured I don't need an instance of any class, but then the `getData()` method in `myBase` class must be static like:

```
static myStruct getData(int index)
{
    return *(myStructArray + index);
}
```

and then call it like `myDerived1::getData(1);` instead of having to make an instance of `getData`.

I cannot get this to work. If figure I should get rid of the constructors as they will only be called when instantiating the classes which I want to avoid. But how to initialize the member variable `myStructArray` in the base class then?

Is this even possible? If someone can modify my example to a fixed working example that would be most informative!

---

Ps. I'm still learning C++ so forgive me if I use e.g. some terminology wrong.

Comment: Do you need `myBase` and why?

Comment: `myBase` class hosts the functionality that I need. I want to define this functionality only once and not 100 times in each derived class. I never use `myBase` directly, I always access this functionality via an instance of a derived class. `myBase` also hosts (generic) functionality that requires an instance of a derived class but I did not include this in the example above. Since my focus in this question is on how to make the functionality available that should not require an instance.
So in summary, `myBase` defines the functionality. Each derived class defines the data.

Comment: Turn `myBase` into CRTP? or Add `const myStruct *` parameter to the function?

Comment: Thanks!! Adding the "const myStruct * parameter to the function" will that work, or to be more specific, will it have performance considerations? Is the constexpr ran each time the function is called (that would be too expensive) or is this somehow optimized away and it gives no performance penalty compared to my current implementation?
If I have many more functions using the data, would the binairy size blow up since the data is repeated over and over again in each function for each derived class?

Comment: Sorry, never mind the comment above, I dont see how this would work. The `myBase` class does not know the constexpr so cannot reference it. Can you clarify?

Comment: How would the CRTP case look like? Im not yet very good in templates and this would become rather complex quickly. I need te template the array type (as the size is not constant). But also the array data (as it differs for each case).

Comment: [Crtp demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KEPWaP9o6)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you so much! I got it working in your example. The only thing I changed was removed the `const` cv-qualifier from `GetData` and added the `static` keyword to the method's declaration.
I can past the working code as an answer, but you can do it to if you want.

Comment: @Jarod42 one more question though if you don't mind, so I learn more from it. Does the way you do this, have performance implications.?Or implications for the binary size? To be more specific: if I have many functions like `GetData` will the data only be stored once or once per function? And is the array only constructed at compile time and stored in the binary (i think so because it is `constexpr`).

Comment: You might post the answer. and there is only one static array by derived class, the function doesn't copy any array.

Comment: *...without having to instantiate it*  This doesn't seem right to me.  What "it" is not being instantiated, per the comment?

Comment: @Jardo42, I created the answer, please check it out. I copied your code, but I changed line 18 to `constexpr static myStruct getData(int index)`. And below I added some (working) tests to access the data without instantiating *the class*.

Answer (score 0):

@Jarod42 provided me with a great solution.

He created a Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP). Because of this pattern, the base class can access members in the derived classed directly.

This makes the base class member in my example obsolete, and thus also removes the need for the derived class to instantiate any base class member.

This is a very ellegant solution and clearly a better approach then I was exploring in the question.

Working example below:

```
#include<array>
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct
{
    int id;
    int size;
};

template <typename Derived>
class myBase
{
public:
    // This functionality is in my real case much more complex.
    // I want to define this functionality only once, and not repeatetly in the derived classes as it will become unmainainable.
    // But since all information is known at compile time and const, I want to be able to access this method staticially as:
    // `myDerived1::getData(1);`, thus without having to instantiate the 'myDerived1' class.
    constexpr static myStruct getData(int index)
    {
        return Derived::myStructArray[index];
    }
};

// An example of a derived class defining the data.
class myDerived1 : public myBase<myDerived1>
{
public:
    constexpr static auto myStructArray{
        []() { // A lambda function that initializes the array as a constexpr where the array indexes are explicitly denoted.
            std::array<myStruct, 2> myStructData{};
            myStructData[0] = {.id = 0, .size = 1};
            myStructData[1] = {.id = 1, .size = 2};
            return myStructData;
        }()};
};

// Another example of the derived class with the same structure but different data.
class myDerived2 : public myBase<myDerived2>
{
public:
    constexpr static auto myStructArray{
        []() { // A lambda function that initializes the array as a constexpr where the array indexes are explicitly denoted.
            std::array<myStruct, 3> myStructData{};
            myStructData[0] = {.id = 0, .size = 8};
            myStructData[1] = {.id = 1, .size = 9};
            myStructData[2] = {.id = 2, .size = 1};
            return myStructData;
        }()};
};

int main() {
    // Like before, accessing the data via an instance of the class still works.
    auto test = myDerived1();
    std::cout << test.getData(0).size << '\n';
    std::cout << test.getData(1).size << '\n';

    // But now, it also works without needing an instance of the class.
    std::cout << myDerived1::getData(0).size << '\n';
    std::cout << myDerived1::getData(1).size << '\n';

    std::cout << myDerived2::getData(0).size << '\n';
    std::cout << myDerived2::getData(1).size << '\n';
};
```